# How do I change the shape of a :hover in the navbar?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, parent-child

I have added a transparent hover on my navbar social icons but i cannot figure out how to change the shape of the hover. It currently looks like this:

[image: Facebook hover]

I'd like the hover to only appear on the icon itself, rather than the space above and below it.

```html
<li id="menu-item-518" class="fb-icon menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-518"><a title="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/linkhere">Facebook</a></li>
```

The CSS of my child theme is currently:

```html
/* Social link hover colour */
.fb-icon.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.menu-item-518 a:hover{
 background-color:transparent;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It has to do with the css of the list item. Right now it looks like the list item itself is transforming into the facebook icon by the use of some class. The list item's height spans beyond the icon itself. If possible, I would suggest using a thumbnail and target that directly instead of the list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` and replace them with `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` if you need them.

so maybe something like this:

```
.my-icon {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! So i took your suggestion of changing the padding and found the bit of code for the navbar that had the padding and got this:

.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
   padding-top: 0px;
   padding-bottom:0px;
}
 
.nav>li>a {
 padding:0px 10px;
}

Thanks!